# Looking to display text on image immediately on click of next/prev button on slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As it currently stands I have a slideshow that fades in specific text on a specific image when it is being automated (which is fine), however it *also* fades in when the next / prev buttons are pressed.  What I want is for the specific text to be displayed to the specific slide *immediately* when the next / prev buttons are clicked and not faded in.

Here is the code, I have tried a few things but nothing is working!  It would be most helpful if a snippet of code can be provided and an explanation of how the syntax has achieved its goal.

```
  var slideIndex = 1; 

          var t;

          showSlides(slideIndex);

            function plusSlides(n) {

                  slideIndex = slideIndex + n;
                  clearTimeout(t);
                  showSlides(slideIndex);
                  console.log(slideIndex);

            }

            function currentSlide(n) {

                  showSlides(slideIndex = n);

            }

            function showSlides(n) {

                  var i;

                  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");

                        if (n==undefined){n = ++slideIndex}

                        if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}

                        if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}

                        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {

                              slides[i].style.display = "none";

                  }

                  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";

                  $(slides[slideIndex-1]).find('#fadeTxt1S1').fadeIn(3000);

                  $(slides[slideIndex-1]).find('#fadeTxt2S1').fadeIn(3000);

                  $(slides[slideIndex-1]).find('#fadeTxt1S2').fadeIn(3000);

                  $(slides[slideIndex-1]).find('#fadeTxt2S2').fadeIn(3000);

                  $(slides[slideIndex-1]).find('#fadeTxt1S3').fadeIn(3000);

                  $(slides[slideIndex-1]).find('#fadeTxt2S3').fadeIn(3000);

                  t=setTimeout(showSlides, 7500)

            };


     #fadeTxt1S1 {

         display: none;
         color: white;
         position: absolute;
         top: 300px;
         left: 250px;
         font-size: 65px;
         font-family: serif;
         font-style: italic;
         opacity: 0.9;
         text-shadow:  2px 2px #9B51E0;

         }

         #fadeTxt2S1 {

         display: none;
         color: white;
         position: absolute;
         bottom: 470px;
         right: 340px;
         font-size: 65px;
         font-family: serif;
         font-style: italic;
         opacity: 0.9;
         text-shadow:  2px 2px #9B51E0;

         }

         #fadeTxt1S2 {

         display: none;
         color: white;
         position: absolute;
         top: 200px;
         left: 300px;
         font-size: 65px;
         font-family: serif;
         font-style: italic;
         opacity: 0.9;
         text-shadow:  2px 2px #9B51E0;

         }

         #fadeTxt2S2 {

         display: none;
         color: white;
         position: absolute;
         bottom: 610px;
         right: 170px;
         font-size: 65px;
         font-family: serif;
         font-style: italic;
         opacity: 0.9;
         text-shadow:  2px 2px #9B51E0;

         }

         #fadeTxt1S3 {

         display: none;
         color: white;
         position: absolute;
         top: 310px;
         right: 110px;
         font-size: 60px;
         font-family: serif;
         font-style: italic;
         opacity: 0.9;
         text-shadow:  2px 2px #9B51E0;

         }

         #fadeTxt2S3 {

         display: none;
         color: white;
         position: absolute;
         bottom: 510px;
         right: 70px;
         font-size: 60px;
         font-family: serif;
         font-style: italic;
         opacity: 0.9;
         text-shadow:  2px 2px #9B51E0;

         }


<html>


     <div id="slideShowContainer">

                 <div class="mySlides fade">

                           <img class="homePageSlides imageCover" src=HomePage/slide3b.jpg">

                           <p id="fadeTxt1S1">"text1 for slide1"</p>

                           <p id="fadeTxt2S1">"text2 for slide1"</p>

                 </div>


                <div class="mySlides fade">

                           <img class="homePageSlides imageCover" src=HomePage/test2.jpg">

                           <p id="fadeTxt1S2">"text1 for slide2"</p>

                           <p id="fadeTxt2S2">"text2 for slide2"</p>

                 </div>

                <div class="mySlides fade">

                           <img class="homePageSlides imageCover" src=HomePage/test3.jpg">

                           <p id="fadeTxt1S3">"text1 for slide3"</p>

                           <p id="fadeTxt2S3">"text2 for slide3"</p>

                 </div>

            <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&lsaquo;</a>

            <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&rsaquo;</a>


      </div>

</html>
```

Comment: Post a working snippet

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you'd like to display the texts of current slide directly when press 'prev/next', then display other texts by default order.

**Below is the codes** *(I updated some codes at the bottom of your Javascript codes)*:

My opinion is adding one offset=`[the index of current slide]` to make sure the texts of current slide will be processed first.

PS: please test the slideshow in full page.

```js
      var slideIndex = 1; 

      var t;

      showSlides(slideIndex);

        function plusSlides(n) {

              slideIndex = slideIndex + n;
              clearTimeout(t);
              showSlides(slideIndex);
              console.log(slideIndex);

        }

        function currentSlide(n) {

              showSlides(slideIndex = n);

        }

        function showSlides(n) {

              var i;

              var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");

                    if (n==undefined){n = ++slideIndex}

                    if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}

                    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}

                    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {

                          slides[i].style.display = "none";

              }

              slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
              // Fade In the texts of all slides in specific order.
              for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
                // calculate out current SlideIndex for text fade in
                var targetIndex = (n+i)%slides.length+1; //(n+i) to make sure current slide will be processed first
                $(slides[slideIndex-1]).find('#fadeTxt1S' + targetIndex).fadeIn(3000);
                $(slides[slideIndex-1]).find('#fadeTxt2S' + targetIndex).fadeIn(3000);
                
              }

              t=setTimeout(showSlides, 7500)

        };
```

```css
     #fadeTxt1S1 {

     display: none;
     color: white;
     position: absolute;
     top: 300px;
     left: 250px;
     font-size: 65px;
     font-family: serif;
     font-style: italic;
     opacity: 0.9;
     text-shadow:  2px 2px #9B51E0;

     }

     #fadeTxt2S1 {

     display: none;
     color: white;
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 470px;
     right: 340px;
     font-size: 65px;
     font-family: serif;
     font-style: italic;
     opacity: 0.9;
     text-shadow:  2px 2px #9B51E0;

     }

     #fadeTxt1S2 {

     display: none;
     color: white;
     position: absolute;
     top: 200px;
     left: 300px;
     font-size: 65px;
     font-family: serif;
     font-style: italic;
     opacity: 0.9;
     text-shadow:  2px 2px #9B51E0;

     }

     #fadeTxt2S2 {

     display: none;
     color: white;
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 610px;
     right: 170px;
     font-size: 65px;
     font-family: serif;
     font-style: italic;
     opacity: 0.9;
     text-shadow:  2px 2px #9B51E0;

     }

     #fadeTxt1S3 {

     display: none;
     color: white;
     position: absolute;
     top: 310px;
     right: 110px;
     font-size: 60px;
     font-family: serif;
     font-style: italic;
     opacity: 0.9;
     text-shadow:  2px 2px #9B51E0;

     }

     #fadeTxt2S3 {

     display: none;
     color: white;
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 510px;
     right: 70px;
     font-size: 60px;
     font-family: serif;
     font-style: italic;
     opacity: 0.9;
     text-shadow:  2px 2px #9B51E0;

     }
     
     .prev {
      font-size:32px;
     }
     .prev:hover {
      font-size:40px;
      color:red;
     }
     
     .next {
      font-size:32px;
     }
     .next:hover {
      font-size:40px;
      color:blue;
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slideShowContainer">

             <div class="mySlides fade">

                       <img class="homePageSlides imageCover" src=HomePage/slide3b.jpg">

                       <p id="fadeTxt1S1">"text1 for slide1"</p>

                       <p id="fadeTxt2S1">"text2 for slide1"</p>

             </div>


            <div class="mySlides fade">

                       <img class="homePageSlides imageCover" src=HomePage/test2.jpg">

                       <p id="fadeTxt1S2">"text1 for slide2"</p>

                       <p id="fadeTxt2S2">"text2 for slide2"</p>

             </div>

            <div class="mySlides fade">

                       <img class="homePageSlides imageCover" src=HomePage/test3.jpg">

                       <p id="fadeTxt1S3">"text1 for slide3"</p>

                       <p id="fadeTxt2S3">"text2 for slide3"</p>

             </div>

        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&lsaquo;</a>

        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&rsaquo;</a>


  </div>
```